# How to associate stream content with a file name without actually writing the content to disk?

Tags: c++, linux, gzip, pcap

I have an interface that reads files of few types. The interface has `read` and `open` methods (and few more). `open` receives a file name (const char*) and opens the file for reading. Currently I support two file types, pcap and raw binary. Recently I discovered that all the files that I'm suppose to read are actually zipped (in gzip format) but other than that all remains the same (after I unzip the files everything works as designed). I would like to add to the open method unzip capability, so first the file will be unzipped (in memory, without writing the unzipped content to disk) and pass the unzipped content to the actual implementations. The main problem is that the `open` implementation expects a file name, in case of pcap the `open` implementation calls `pcap_open_offline` which doesn't receive a stream or a buffer. Ideally I would be able to create some sort of a file (pipe, link or whatever) and to associate it with the content I extracted from the zipped file. Any idea how can I do it? here is a little code to make it easier to understand what I'm doing

```
class FileReader //interface
{
public:
 void open(const char* name)
 {
  // unzip file here
  open_impl(name);
 }
 virtual size_t read() = 0;
protected:
 virtual void open_impl(const char* name) = 0;
};

class PcapReader: public FileReader
{
public:
 size_t read() {...}
protected:
 virtual void open_impl(const char* name)
 {
   pcap_open_offline(name, error_buffer);
 }
 char error_buffer[1024];
};
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354553/lightweight-library-for-reading-zip-files

Comment: Looks like there is function to read from a FILE pointer: `pcap_fopen_offline` ( with `f` ). This is not usable?

Comment: This is actually a great point, I'll try to see if I can use it.

Comment: To complement @tivn's point, there's `fmemopen` which will make you a `FILE*` out of a chunk of memory

Comment: This is a great comment too, I'll see if I can put things together